# Create swagger yaml for empty json array object

Tags: yaml, swagger

One of my objects in response is kept as empty. I am unable to create the swagger yaml for that part.

```
... <<something>>
,
        "dummy": [
          {}
        ],
... <<something>>
```

I have written below piece:

```
..... <<something>>
dummy:
        $ref: '#/definitions/dummy'
..... <<something>>
    dummy:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: "#/definitions/dumm"
      dumm:
        properties:
          type: "object"
```

The error seen is `"should be object"` in front of the last line above.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct definition of your model would be:

```
  dummy:
    type: array
    items:
      $ref: "#/definitions/dumm"

  dumm:
    type: "object"
```

Do not use `properties` if the model does not have any of them.